# What Happened to BufferedImage class in Java ME 6?

Tags: java, netbeans, java-me, netbeans6.5

from my small knowlegde from java se i want to try a tutorial on Java ME.I have Netbeans 6.5.1(with mobility package) and have Java 6 update 13 installed on my windows xp sp2.I've arrived on a stage of the tutorials where they are using BufferedImage that seems not to be found either on java.io, java.nio.Buffer, javax.microedition.io, or javax.microedition.m3g.Image2D.

This is the coce from the tutorial

```
ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(getService().getDailyDilbertSoap().dailyDilbertImage());
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(in);
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(image, "png", out);
    return out.toByteArray();
```

How do I achieve this?what is the replacement for the BufferedImage?Is it deprecated?.It's seems to be not much info on the web unless i'm looking for it somewhere else.

Comment: Java ME classes are a stripped down versions of the J2SE classes or rather classes tuned for performance in mobile phones that have less processing power and resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're talking about [this](http://www.netbeans.org/kb/60/mobility/mobile-dilbert.html) tutorial:

The code you've pasted above does not run on the Java ME device.  It is deployed on Glassfish (the application server) in the web service implementation that is consumed by the Java ME client.

Comment: yeah that's it.Same tuto.Now that i'm realizing that they are talking about the web service proxy.mmmh that was careless from me.Sorry for the bother.Since i'm using the netbeans 6.5.1 whose environment was a slight change, i'm abit confused.Thanks man!